# javadoc: error cannot read Input length = 1 (IntelliJ - no maven)

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

I found many questions about this, but no one solved my problem, however I am goind to show you **how to solve it** :)

When generating the Javadoc I got the follwing issue:
javadoc: error - cannot read Input length = 1

It seems that after all, IntelliJ does not like special characters, in the project **AND in the path** where the project is located.

1st - I moved the project to C:\
2nd - I set the following line in the "Other command line arguments:"
`-encoding utf8 -docencoding utf8 -charset utf8`

(this line is coppied from here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.1/working-with-code-documentation.html#generate-javadoc)

It exported everything without any problem.

I hope it helps! :)